example of non-compactly supported vector field.
Definition: A vector field X on M is complete if for any p $\in$ M, there is an integral curve $ \gamma: R \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$.
Note: every smooth vector field over a compact manifold is complete.
Consider the vector field X = $t^2\frac{d}{dt}$ on R. Since the integral curves starting at any $ c\neq0$ is not defined for all $t \in R$, we conclude that X is not complete.
By contrapositive, we get X = $t^2\frac{d}{dt}$ on R is not smooth. But coefficient function $t^2$ is smooth. where am I wrong? 
Theorem: If X is a compactly supported vector field on M, then it is complete.
Can anyone give a simple example of compactly supported vector field on some manifold to get intuitive idea and one non-example? 
I tried some simple vector fields on the unit circle which seems a compactly supported. But I am far away from general idea. Thanks

“Smooth vector field is complete” is wrong, idk where you got that from. For an example of compactly supported vector field, just replace your coefficient $t^2$ with some bump function $\chi(t)$ for example. Or look at any vector field on a compact manifold (like the spheres $S^n$, in particular for $S^1$ you can even visualize the unit tangent vector field which rotates you around the circle).

@peek-a-boo I think I missed the "over a compact manifold" part. I have corrected it now.

For a compactly supported example, as suggested in the comments just take any vector field on a compact manifold. E.g. consider the vector field $X_{(x,y)} = x\partial_y - y\partial_x$ on the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$. The flow associated to this is counterclockwise rotation.
For non-compactly supported examples, just consider the constant vector field $X = \partial_{x^1}$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$.
Also, as pointed out in the comments it isn't clear what you mean by "every smooth vector field is complete" since $t^2\partial_t$ on $\Bbb{R}$ is a counterexample.
